# can anyone tell me whats wrong with this IIS URL rewrite?

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

So i should be able to visit rsstest/test.xml and be forwarded to article.xml if i don't have a user agent of wibble.

why doesn't this work?

`<rule name="df" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^rsstest/test.xml" negate="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Wibble" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="article.xml" />
            </rule>`

thanks in advance

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the `^` in the URL and the fact that you are using `ExactMatch`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried taking this out to no avail.

Comment: When you say you want to be forwarded, do you mean redirect instead of rewrite?

Comment: yeah, i just want to visit rsstest/test.xml and be forwarded (like a 302 redirect in apache) to article.xml

Comment: Can you keep the previous change and change `<action type=Rewrite` to `<action type="Redirect`? Do you have access to the IIS Manager or are you just changing the web.config file?

Comment: i have access to the IIS Manager, and changed the "Action type" under the "action" header to redirect. Still nothing.

Comment: I figured this out, thanks for your help! it should be set to "exact match", keep the ^ in, and set to redirect not rewrite. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the rule to this.

```
<rule name="df" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true"> 
    <match url="^rsstest/test.xml" negate="true" /> 
    <conditions> 
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Wibble" negate="true" />
    </conditions> 
    <action type="Redirect" url="article.xml" /> 
</rule>
```

Using redirect sends a HTTP 301 or 302 to the client, telling the client that it should try to access the page using another URL.

Rewriting happens on the server, and simply is a translation of one URL to another, that is used by your web application. The client will not see any change.